# meteor update callback shortcut by latency compensation?

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, meteor

I have these methods in my "transaction" model. They are present both on client and server:

```
Meteor.methods

  addMatching: (invoice, transaction) ->
    amount_open = if transaction.amount_open then transaction.amount_open else transaction.amount
    amount = Math.min(invoice.amount_open,amount_open)
    invoice_nbr = if invoice.invoice_nbr then invoice.invoice_nbr else "999999"
    Transactions.update(transaction._id, {$push:{matchings:{invoice_id: invoice._id, invoice_nbr: invoice_nbr, amount: amount }}}, (e, r) ->
      if e
        console.log e
      else
        Invoices.update(invoice._id, {$inc: {amount_open: - amount}})
        Meteor.call "updateAmountOpen", transaction
    )


  updateAmountOpen: (transaction) ->
    amount_matched = 0
    transaction.matchings.map (matching) ->
      amount_matched = amount_matched + matching.amount
    total = transaction.amount - amount_matched
    Transactions.update(transaction._id, {$set: {amount_open: total}}, (e, r) ->
      if e
        console.log e
    )
```

When I call "addMatching", an object is added in the "matchings" array of the "transactions" collection.

After, adding this object, I want to recompute the total of matchings for the transactions and update it with the "updateAmount" method.

I don't know why but "updateAmount" seems to be running before the end of the update done on "matchings".

It is inside a callback though.

Is this a problem related to latency compensation? Do I have to put these methods server side or is there a solution as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fetch a document from a collection (call `cursor.fetch` or `collection.findOne`), you get a JavaScript object representing the document at that time. That JavaScript object won't be affected by updates to the document in the collection. So instead of:

```js
Meteor.call "updateAmountOpen", transaction
```

You need to fetch it again, so you get the field you updated up-to-date:

```js
Meteor.call "updateAmountOpen", Transaction.findOne(transaction._id)
```